# How to add a Client Web Part in SharePoint provider hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to retrieve data from SharePoint lists (office 365) in a client web part created in SharePoint provider hosted app.
The majority of tutorials i found were about SP hosted app.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to read lists that are available in host web. Make sure you app has read permission

```
var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context);

using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
{
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    ListCollection lists = clientContext.Web.Lists;
    List list = lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");

    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load<ListCollection>(lists);
    clientContext.Load<List>(list);
    clientContext.Load<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection>(items);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
    {
        Response.Write("<br />" + item.FieldValues["Title"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I publish my app only the first field is retrieved,how can I read all the fields of the SP list please?

Comment: can you more explain for me please it doesn't work :/

Comment: Take a look at this link.. it shows how to use clientContext.Load... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956%28v=office.14%29.aspx